# Ubuntu Screen Resolution

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, display

How do I change the screen resolution in Ubuntu? I am dual booting Vista and Ubuntu. The preferences tab only has one resolution option for my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find xorg.conf in /etc/X11/
Edit it with any editor you have and like, but that won't fix the problem with the wrong driver.

You can try to go through this HowTo from Ubuntu to fix your problem. Hopefully it'll help.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 1):

Then it probably didn't recognise your video card (did you install the proprietary drivers if you are using an NVidia or ATI card?) or your monitor. If you are using the right drivers already you will probably have to edit your [xorg.conf](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html) manually and add the reolution you want.

Comment: It didn't. I have an Inspiron with an ATI Radeon and it isn't recognized. How do I edit the xorg.conf and what do I need to change? What directory is it in?